# How to create snap YAML file of program written in golang sciter library?

Tags: go, yaml, snapcraft, sciter

could you please help me? How to create YAML file for golang application written in language go named golang and sciter library https://sciter.com/ ? I mean how what to write to yaml file to have working snap for snapcraft store? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter"
    "github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter/window"
)

func main() {
    w, err := window.New(sciter.SW_TITLEBAR|sciter.SW_RESIZEABLE|sciter.SW_CONTROLS|sciter.SW_MAIN|sciter.SW_ENABLE_DEBUG, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // log.Printf("handle: %v", w.Handle)
    w.LoadFile("simple.html")
    w.SetTitle("Example")
    w.Show()
    w.Run()
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to answer here

Comment: missing the point? is there somewhere docs on this my google did not find? I didn't see any reasonable examples for beginners.. All right then, there is nothing to answer here as you say

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too special with Sciter other than the requirement that libsciter-gtk.so to be installed (copied) in the same folder as resulting go executable.

So you will have basic Go rules: https://docs.snapcraft.io/go-applications/7818
and libsciter-gtk.so (x64) listed in fileset : https://docs.snapcraft.io/snapcraft-filesets/8973